# How Can I dynamically mask all digits except the last 4 always?

Tags: javascript

How Can I mask all the digits that the user to input, dynamically?

Scenario 1:
User input: 1234 5678 9123 4414
Output: xxxx xxxx xxxx 4414

Scenario 2:
User input: 12345678 8234245
Output: xxxxxxxx xxx4245

Scenario 3:
User input: 12 345678911
Output: xx xxxxx8911

What I have is a fix only and it is static, How can I make my code to be dynamic? so that I can lessen my if else statement?

```
function hideMask(num) {
    
  var regExp = /[a-zA-Z]/g;
  
  if(regExp.test(num)){
     return null;
  } else {
    if(num.replace(/\s/g, '').length == 16){ // 16 digit
    mask = num.substring(num.length - 14).replace(/\d/g,"x");
    unmaskCardNumber = num.substring(14, 19);
    return(mask + unmaskCardNumber);
  }else if(num.replace(/\s/g, '').length == 18){ //18 digit
    mask = num.substring(0,15).replace(/\d/g,"x");
    unmaskCardNumber = num.substring(15, 19);
    return(mask + unmaskCardNumber);
  }else{
    return null;
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: There is an `if`, then an `else`, then an `else if` and finally an `else`. That makes no sense. You can remove the last two conditions.

Comment: ```return num.replace(/(.*)(.{4})/, (_, a, b) => 'x'.repeat(a.length) + b)```

Comment: @deceze As far as I understand, it's not required that the last 4 digits are continuously. Scenario 4: 123456 78 is missing.

Comment: I hope that you are transforming these data on server side, before giving it to the frontend, because it could be a problem regarding security. I mean, if you transform it on frontend, I am pretty sure that I could easelly get these card number with a quick look at it as a developer (without specific hacking skills...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily achieve the result using [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [`reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) and [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
function mask(s) {
  let count = 0;
  return s
    .split("")
    .reverse()
    .map((n, i) => (!n.match(/\d/) ? n : count < 4 ? (count++, n) : "x"))
    .reverse()
    .join("");
}
```

```js
function mask(s) {
  let count = 0;
  return s
    .split("")
    .reverse()
    .map((n, i) => {
      if (!n.match(/\d/)) return n;
      else {
        return count < 4 ? (count++, n) : "x";
      }
    })
    .reverse()
    .join("");
}

console.log(mask("1234 5678 9123 4414"));
console.log(mask("12345678 8234245"));
console.log(mask("12 345678911"));
console.log(mask("12 345678 9 1 1")); //  CORNER CASE
```

You can even skip `reverse` step if you use `reduceRight` as:

```
function mask(s) {
  let count = 0;
  return s
    .split("")
    .reduceRight((acc, n, i) => {
      acc.push(!n.match(/\d/) ? n : count < 4 ? (count++, n) : "x");
      return acc;
    }, [])
    .reverse()
    .join("");
}
```

```js
function mask(s) {
  let count = 0;
  return s
    .split("")
    .reduceRight((acc, n, i) => {
      acc.push(!n.match(/\d/) ? n : count < 4 ? (count++, n) : "x");
      return acc;
    }, [])
    .reverse()
    .join("");
}

console.log(mask("1234 5678 9123 4414"));
console.log(mask("12345678 8234245"));
console.log(mask("12 345678 9 1 1"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go about it, using [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), and [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):
First replace all alphanumeric characters in the string, bar the last four with 'x', and append the last four from before:

```js
function mask(input) {
  return input
    .slice(0, input.length - 4)
    .replace(/([a-zA-Z0-9])/g, 'x') + input.slice(-4)
}
console.log(mask('abcd efgh 1234 5678'))
```

Comment: This is not the correct solution because It will fail if you give input as `mask("12 345678 9 1 1")`

Comment: @decpk I can't find where "12 345678 9 1 1" is a use case and in this context, what does in mean to 'fail'? I think you are putting up criterias that are not part of the problem/solution.

Answer (score 0):

I saw somewhere that you can slice the input string and replace:

```js
function mask(input) {
  return input.slice(0, -4).replace(/./g, '#') + input.slice(-4);
}
console.log(mask('1234567890'));
```